# Ionic Framework Plist with IOS10

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I don't know if Ionic has released an official documentation for this issue, but when I try to use my camera plugin the app crashes and Xcode leaves me this lovely report:

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

I understand why this is happening I just don't know where and how to fix this.

Comment: Check this link: http://cordobo.com/2256-fix-ioniccordova-app-ios-10-nscamerausagedescription-permission/

Comment: Thank You, This did the trick! would mind posting as an answer? @LoVo

Comment: welcome and done ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [link](http://cordobo.com/2256-fix-ioniccordova-app-ios-10-nscamerausagedescription-permission/) that should help you.